# Installation problems with django-tagging

Tags: python, django, django-tagging

I am having problems using [django-tagging](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/). I try to follow the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/django-tagging/source/browse/trunk/docs/overview.txt) but it fails at the second step

> Once you've installed Django Tagging and want to use it in your Django applications, do the following:
>
> 1. Put `'tagging'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.
> 2. Run the command `manage.py syncdb`.
>
> The `syncdb` command creates the necessary database tables and creates permission objects for all installed apps that need them.

I get a python Traceback with the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name parse_lookup
```

The following works, so I think it is correctly installed:

```
>> import tagging
>> tagging.VERSION
(0, 2.1000000000000001, None)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7680

parse_lookup has been removed. Not sure how this will affect tagging. Might want to do some searching.

Update: apparently it's been fixed in the trunk version of tagging. Download the latest SVN build of tagging.

Comment: Still have this problem with `tagging` 5 years later

Answer (score 0):

I had the same bug me recently. I checked out the trunk release which seems to work fine.

```
In [1]: import tagging; tagging.VERSION
Out[1]: (0, 3, 'pre')
```